# Previously working VB6 program now fails on one PC when opening an excel 2010 spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vb6, windows-xp

I have a problem that has just started with an existing VB6 program. The same program still works on other PCs. All the PCs are XP (SP 3) including where the program fails and should, in theory, have the same build.

The code  fails when trying to open an excel 2010 spreadsheet. 
The error is

error method ~ of object ~ failed

I searched this error on the web and a suggestion was to try "Dependency Walker" On the failing PC this reported
MPR.DLL  and SHLWAPI.DLL  as Delay load dependency module not found

On a working PC only MPR was reported as a warning

SHLWAPI.DLL is present on the failing PC.
I tried to register SHLWAPI but this will not register

The code

```
Public Sub Populate_booked(sched_file)
   On Error GoTo Populate_booked_error
   Dim xl As New Excel.Application
   Dim xl2 As New Excel.Application
   Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(sched_file)
```

The Set xlwbook line fails

sched_file is an excel file on a LAN drive. The failing PC has full read/write access to the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: SHLWAPI is a core operating system library and is not registerable as its not an automation server, this sound more likely to be an issue with Excels automation, you could try EXCEL.EXE –REGSERVER

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion:

Change your code to:

```
Public Sub Populate_booked(sched_file)
   On Error GoTo Populate_booked_error
   Dim xl As Excel.Application
   Dim xl2 As Excel.Application

   Set xl = New Excel.Application
   Set xl2 = New Excel.Application

   Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(sched_file)
```

This won't really fix your problem, but it will narrow down the possible reasons.  In your current code, the line

```
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(sched_file)
```

will do two things:

1. Since this is the first time you use the xl variable and it is Dim'd as New, the program will create a new Excel.Application instance.
2. Open the file (if 1 was successful).

The change will enable you to know if it is part 1 or 2 that is failing.